# java gson - is it possible to deserialize an object from a string without having all of its fields

Tags: java, gson, xml-deserialization

Lets say I am adding a field to the object and I still get the same string . Can I de-Json it into an object with the missing fields set as null?
what if I have primitive variables there ? 
10x

Comment: Can you provide some example or more clarification. This is a pretty vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depends on how the deserialization is done. If the object is first created with a no-arg constructor and then the fields are set via setters or reflection, I'd say this should work. In that case, every reference to other objects would be null whereas primitive types get their default values (for numbers 0, for boolean false, etc.)

Comment: this is still a problem . in the old clients, i will get a gson string with new fieds. they throw an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace of the IllegalArgumentException? It might be some field that should never be null.

Comment: My mistake. Double checked and it does work the way you described. I forgot to make a string replace to the newer class nae before using  GSON on it.

Comment: Yes, thats is the issue, i was using primitive types , which was giving me default values

Answer (score 0):

You can use XStream to (de)serialize to JSON, and this is how they deal with new fields: http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization_newer_class_versions

So the short answer is: references will be null references, primitives will keep the values they got in constructor

Comment: Can I do it with GSON ? my project uses GSON and I would like to stay with this jar ( unless I would have to transform to an alternative)

Comment: "If a field is removed from the class, deserializing an old version that contains the field will cause an exception."   so this means I will have to upgrade all my clients. i would like to find a solution to avoid it. 10x

Comment: In that case, you can use @Since annotation which was designed exactly for your case: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Versioning-Support

Answer (score 0):

Yes

[Gson - Finer Points with Objects](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects)

While deserialization, a missing entry in JSON results in setting the corresponding field in the object to null